# DataTables: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, but the JSON is valid

Tags: datatables

```
var deptTable = $('#team-table').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/cc/AjaxDashboard/getMyTeam",
    "pageLength": 10,
    "scrollY": "250px"
});
```

I have this. The JSON response is just `[]` as there's no data. I am getting:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I thought `[]` was valid JSON as per https://jsonlint.com/ and it would show an empty message but I get an error instead

Comment: For DataTables, an empty response should work if you use `{}` (empty object), not `[]` (empty array) as your JSON response. However, I get a different error from you when I use `[]` - so maybe there's something else going on.

Comment: Re: your data attributes question, *don't* delete questions just because you came across the answer. It doesn't mean your question is invalid, or that it won't be of help to others - and others take the time to write you answers.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is indeed a valid JSON syntax for empty array. The reason you're getting the error is because the data returned from your AJAX doesn't match the DataTable's default expectation.

There are 3 ways you can use with the `ajax` option:

- Give it a string as the AJAX source
- Give it a configuration object
- Give it a function

And by default, when the AJAX source is given, DataTables expects the returned data to be an array of items with the key `data`:

```js
{
    data: []
}
```

If your AJAX doesn't return this format, you will get that error. Here is the proof: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/s2xgof6t/22/

To fix it, you can override the returned format by setting `dataSrc` to an empty string, like this:

```
{
    ajax: {
        url: xxx,
        dataSrc: ''
    }
}
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/s2xgof6t/26/

More reads on this custom data source property: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html